# K8s/Helm - how to mount volume based on value attribute?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have the values file with some attributes that will be used on mount volumes. As example:

```yaml
secrets:
  my-secret:
    as: volume
    key: file.xml
    mountPath: /etc/xml
```

I'm trying to mount volumes only if the value of `as` is `volume`:

```yaml
          volumeMounts:
          {{- range $name, $value := .Values.secrets }}
            {{- if eq $value.as "volume" }}
            - name: {{ $name }}-volume
              mountPath: {{ quote $value.mountPath }}
            {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
```

For some reason, it's failing:

```sh
Error: Deployment.apps "webanalytics" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "my-secret-volume"
```

Any idea on what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The logs show that you are accessing `"my-secret-volume"`.  But that has to exist in your Kubernetes cluster in the same namespace. The error shows that it doesn't exist so you have to [create it](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) ⚒️.

Because you didn't share the whole template it could be that the secrets is actually created by the Helm template but it has a different name from `"my-secret-volume"`

☮️✌️

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood,

```
secrets:
  my-secret:             // this is the name of your secret
    as: volume           // when this value is "volume", you mount it; otherwise, it's ignored
    key: file.xml        // contents of the secret named "my-secret"
    mountPath: /etc/xml
```

So ultimately, the secret will be named `my-secret`. I think you should try by removing `-volume` in deployment template like below:

```
      volumeMounts:
          {{- range $name, $value := .Values.secrets }}
            {{- if eq $value.as "volume" }}
            - name: {{ $name }}
              mountPath: {{ quote $value.mountPath }}
            {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
```

Above logic only works if :

1. The `secret/my-secret` is created in helm template.
2. The template of secret doesn't have `-volume` hardcoded and name is taken dynamically from `Values.yaml`